# Dynamically change Owin configuration values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, owin, owin-middleware

I am using Owin pipeline and in startup.auth.cs setting the application cookie interval as below
     timeout=Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeOut"]);

```
           // Owin Middleware3 - Cookie Authentication Middleware

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout),
                SlidingExpiration = true

                }
            });
```

When I change the value of SessionTimeout in web.config I needs to restart IIS to take t he new values as startup.auth.cs is called only first time. Is there anyway I can dynamically change the cookie expiretimespan without restarting IIS. I am also using kento.authservices for single sign on where I configure in startup.auth.cs. I needs to change the configuration values in this as well dynamically. Please can you help on this.

Comment: I believe you just do nothing and don't need to restart IIS as when you change web.config, that makes application pool restarts as well

Comment: Thanks Cuong. But some of the configuration values in startup.auth.cs is taking from the database. When the application starts in startup.auth.cs the value will be taking from the database. But after the user logs in these values are getting changed in the database through an admin page and after the user logs out and start again the new changed values should taken place but that is not happening as startup.auth.cs is only called once when first time the application starts. How can I dynamically change these values.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing a new object CookieAuthenticationOptions to UseCookieAuthentication , you can keep a reference and pass the reference.It would then enable you to set the ExpireTimeSpan when it changes.

CookieAuthenticationOptions Co = new CookieAuthenticationOptions();

And then set Co.ExpireTimeSpan in the code when the value changes.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. Please can you provide a link or an example which does the same for reference.

Comment: In your case , you can make the following change : CookieAuthenticationOptions co = new CookieAuthenticationOptions(new PathString("/Account/Login"),DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout),true);   app.UseCookieAuthentication(co); Then when the new value is retrieved from the database you can assign it to co.ExpiresTimeSpan :- Co.ExpiresTimeSpan = <new value from database>;You can now access the value ExpiresTImeSpan in the CookieAuthenticationOptions object through the reference co

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. But I am retrieving the expire timespan from another page. In that page the app which is ( IAppbuilder ) is not available, to assign the new cookie authenticationoptions.